# How to monitor Istio stats based on URI using prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh, observability, istio-prometheus

We are using Istio 1.15.4 on EKS 1.23.6.
Our application URL has customer id in it, for eg. https://neeleshgurjar.co.in/api/v1/customer_11

https://neeleshgurjar.co.in/api/v1/customer_12

All requests are landing on Istio Ingress Gateway i.e. AWS managed ALB.

Now how can I monitor the number of request for customer_11 and same for customer_12?

I want to monitor them using Prometheus - grafana stack.

Comment: I see a few options here. You could probably try to figure some variation of this: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/classify-metrics/. It doesn't look like Istio/Envoy by default collect metrics by path. I think a more elegant way would be to either publish these metrics from the application (or create an exporter sidecar to handle this), or better yet expose telemetry through something like OpenTelemetry, which would allow you to unlock extremely robust observability metrics like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/

you can refer to this

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  values:
    telemetry:
      v2:
        prometheus:
          configOverride:
            inboundSidecar:
              metrics:
                - name: requests_path
                  dimensions:
                    request_host: request.path
            gateway:
              metrics:
                - name: requests_path
                  dimensions:
                    request_host: request.path
```